# How to call remote EJB from different JVM and Servers?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Ok, I know that for everything exists a specification, but, it takes compatibility?

Can I invoke an application EJB 3 (JEE5) deployed on JBOSS from an architecture based on EJB 3.1 (JEE6) deployed on Weblogic?

Comment: If you mean "invoke an EJB running on a JBoss A/S from an application concurrently running on a different, Weblogic A/S", then it sounds like you probably want to wrap your EJB in a web service.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your EJB 3.0 module exposes a remote interface, then you can call it from an EJB 3.1 client through that remote interface (using RMI/IIOP).

With regards to the comment made on your question: I wouldn't rush to wrap your EJB 3.0 module with a Web Service layer. It looks nice on diagrams, but when all is said and done, it boils down to requirements and cost/benefit. If your EJB 3.0 module is only going to be called by an EJB client, then a standard remote interface is enough. Having said that, you should define your EJB's interfaces in such a way that will allow you to wrap it with a Web Services layer in the future, *should you need to*.

**NOTE**: You'll have to ensure that the application servers that you are using support calling from one version to another. For example, IBM WebSphere will work when calling from a WAS 6.0 to WAS 7.0. JBoss presents a few challenges (see comments below).

Comment: It's not that simple. Calling remote EJBs between different Java EE servers is really badly supported. Even calls between say JBoss 5 and JBoss 6 are not supported. Only Java SE to one remote Java EE server is officially supported.

Comment: @MikeBraun, some references would be appreciated. Anyhow, if there are factors that make cross-server EJB calls impossible for you, then OK, go ahead and wrap one of them as a web service. My message was that one shouldn't rush to create web service wrapper just for the fun of it.

Comment: Mike is right. Cross app server binary EJB communication is a major oversight in the EJB specification. The problem is that most products need something they call a 'client lib', but this client lib is pretty much the entire server. This means it includes tons of things like the EJB, JPA, JMS etc API classes, which then class with those in the source server. It's even worse between versions of the same AS, since even more clashes. I've tried for a long time to get this to work but eventually gave up. For JBoss AS 5 & 6, see https://community.jboss.org/thread/162519

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Well, on the other end of the scale, WebSphere works just fine when calling from 6.0 to 7.0.

Comment: I learned something too then, that WebSphere does work ;) But in general it's a hit 'n miss thing. Some combinations work, some don't. You can never be sure without simply trying.